# Seleccionar con JS según el class de HTML en vez de por el ID

Tags: javascript

Buenas,

Quería seleccionar con JS los elementos no por el ID, sino por la class, dado que es una estructura que se repite varias veces en el código y me obligaría a crear ID distintas para cada vez que se repite la estructura. He probado con esto:

```
<div id="seccion_logro_mensajes" class="seccion_logro">
    <div id="total_mensajes" class="imagen_logro">
         <img src="" alt="">
    </div>
<div id="info_logro">
    <div class="tracking_logro">
        <p>Numéro de mensajes</p>
        <p><?php echo $total_mensajes ?>/1.000</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tracking_logro">
       <p><i>Logro desbloqueado al <?php echo ($total_mensajes/1000)*100 ?>%</i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="progreso_logro">
       <div class="fondo_logro">
           <div id="barra_logro_mensajes">

           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

La única id que tendría que usar sería `barra_logro_mensajes` porque varía para cada caso. Pensaba que podía usar `getElementsByClass` pero no me funciona. No sé si hay alguna otra forma para escoger esos elementos y evitar crear una `id` distinta para cada caso.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para seleccionar todos los elementos de una clase particular el método es:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("tracking_logro");
```

Esto devolverá una colección con todos los elementos que tengan la clase **tracking_logro**.
Nota: Si se quieren traer todos los elementos que cumplan con 2 clases, se pueden pasar ambas como parámetros, separados por un espacio.

---

También existe una alternativa:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".tracking_logro");
```

En este caso el parámetro del método es un selector CSS. Con lo cual, se puede acceder a un mayor número de elementos.

Nota: En ambos casos, no se restringe el uso desde el elemento *document*. Sino que puede pasarse cualquier otro elemento y buscar entre sus hijos.

---

## Diferencias para los curiosos:

- *getElementsByClassName* devuelve un *HTMLCollection* de elementos **vivos**. Mientras que *querySelectorAll* devuelve un *NodeList* de elementos **estáticos**.

Esto se puede ilustrar en el siguiente ejemplo:

Dado el html:

```
<div class="elemento"></div>
<div class="elemento"></div>
<div class="elemento"></div>
<div class="elemento"></div>
```

Entonces, desde js:

```
let estaticos = document.querySelectorAll(".elemento");
let vivos = document.getElementsByClassName("elemento");

estaticos[1].className = "diferente";    //Mutando la Clase
vivos[2].className = "ladilla-feliz";    //Mutando la Clase

estaticos.length; // -> 4
vivos.length;     // -> 2!
```

La lista de elementos *estáticos* sigue manteniendo referencia a *todos los elementos* de la lista a pesar que algunos ya no cumplan con ser de la clase *elemento*.

Mientras que la lista de elementos *vivos*, solo mantiene referencia *a los elementos que siguen manteniendo la clase*.

- *querySelectorAll* devuelve una lista que permite ser iterada usando *forEach()*.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".elemento").forEach(
  elemento => console.log("Funciona!")         // ->  Funciona! x4
);
document.getElementsByClassName("elemento").forEach(
  elemento => console.log("No :(")            //  ->  forEach is not a function..
);
```

- *querySelectorAll* es soportado desde IE 8, aunque en él solo pueden usarse selectores CSS 2.0.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo único que no consigo coger el `width` de los elementos del ejemplo. He probado con `document.getElementsByClassName("tracking_logro").width;`, `document.getElementsByClassName("tracking_logro").style.width;` y `document.getElementsByClassName("tracking_logro").offsetWidth;` y nada

Comment: El método devuelve un Array con **todos los elementos**. Al hacer por ejemplo ".style", lo estarías haciendo sobre el elemento Array, no sobre el elemento HTML. Deberías recorrer el Array y acceder a la propiedad del elemento 1 por 1. Como nota adicional, no podrás acceder al width del elemento si antes no le pusiste algún valor por css, salvo uses otro método: window.getComputedStyle